# Xamarin - AutoComplete appear in wrong position

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I am using autocomplete inside recyclerAdapter

Here is my code

```
viewHolder.itemName.AfterTextChanged += ItemName_AfterTextChanged;

...
..
.


private void ItemName_AfterTextChanged(object sender, AfterTextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExtAutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteItemName = (ExtAutoCompleteTextView)sender;
            int position = int.Parse(autoCompleteItemName.Tag.ToString());
            autoCompleteItemName.AfterTextChanged -= ItemName_AfterTextChanged;
            HandleAutoComplete(position);
            autoCompleteItemName.AfterTextChanged += ItemName_AfterTextChanged;
        }


private void HandleAutoComplete(int position)
        {

            // check position is correct
            ItemCustomViewHolder PassViewHolder = FindViewHolderByPoistion(position);
             matchedItems = itemDAL.GetMatchedName(PassViewHolder.itemName.Text);
                CustomAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, matchedItems.Select(c => c.TradeNameEn).ToList());
                PassViewHolder.itemName.Adapter = arrayAdapter;

        }

public ItemCustomViewHolder FindViewHolderByPoistion(object tag)
        {
            int pos; 
            int.TryParse(tag.ToString() , out pos);

            //View child = recyclerView.GetChildAt(pos );   
                return (mRecylerView.FindViewHolderForLayoutPosition(pos)) as ItemCustomViewHolder; 
        }
```

here is my issue when I write in last view auto Complete list appear in wrong place any tips how can I fix my issue

[image]

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem? There are too many custom classes in your codes(ex:`ExtAutoCompleteTextView`).